# Hierarchical data grid example vmware clarity

Tags: datagridview, hierarchical, vmware-clarity

I have data in json formate and I want to show that in Datagrid. It should display as root-child format. sample pics is attached. 
Can someone please help me how can I do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0qYV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like you want to use the Stack View feature. Its not a full datagrid with search/filtering, but has hierarchy.

https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/stack-view

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, But I need table format and searching/sorting same as datagrid. Stack-view doesn't fit in my requirement.

I think datagrid's expandable-row functionality can help here but i am not sure how to implement my requirement using it! 
https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/datagrid/expandable-rows